# Create method by selecting lines Java

Tags: java, ide

Folks, I have the following lines

```
oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu","12/10/2014","description 1");
oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu2","13/10/2014","description 2");
oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu3","14/10/2014","description 3");
```

I want to select the 3 lines above and be able to create a Public/Private method call? is this possible in Java and create somehitng like this, by using a shortcut in Java IDE (intelliJ)

```
private static void myfunctionamehere(){

    oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu","12/10/2014","description 1");
    oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu2","13/10/2014","description 2");
    oDBHelper.insertLista("Cadu3","14/10/2014","description 3");

}
```

and where the 3 lines used to be have a new call to the newly created method

Comment: This is called the "extract method" refactoring. IntelliJ can certainly do this (I don't know the shortcut off hand but the words "extract method" should be enough for you to look it up).

Answer (score 3):

Both Eclipse and IntelliJ (Meaning Android Studio, and the likes) support the `extract method` refactoring tool. Just right click, hit `refactor`. Then `extract` and `method`.

Simply follow the onscreen dialog instructions after that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shortcut
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>